# Volume Exceeds 'Windows Mixer' limits

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

I own a pair of Razer's Man'O'War wireless headphones and for some reason they are freaking out sometimes, raising the volumes to levels that are not even possible when following my Windows Mixer. Check out the screenshot I've attached below to understand it all.
*Is there a way to globally limit them? I don't care if it'll screw the mixer- I would never use more than 30% volume on them since they can get VERY loud.*

[image: Volume exceeds 'Windows Mixer' limit - Screenshot]

Thanks everyone, Best regards =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after a long long search today (Quarantined :D) I had found the solution online.
So.. credit to a guy on reddit:

```
I solved the problem with the help from the comments below! Summarized I did the following:

open registry

**go to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render"**

select the "Properties" keys of each renderer listed (long hash values)

look through the values and search for the name of the desired audio output (in my case there were entries like "Q2577W", which is my monitor and "INTELAUDIO" which is the Intel High Definition Auduio driver) -> details ans pictures see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/equalizerapo/discussion/general/thread/cf7a7d4f/#5613

if you found the right renderer which contains the strings from you desired audio output, add a new key called "FxProperties" (if it isn't already there)

if there is a prompt that you don't have enough permissions, apply the following to the "Renderer" key: https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/

Inside the "FxProperties" key, add the following entries from type "String":

**{d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},1 with value {62dc1a93-ae24-464c-a43e-452f824c4250}
{d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},2 with value {637c490d-eee3-4c0a-973f-371958802da2}
{d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},3 with value {5860E1C5-F95C-4a7a-8EC8-8AEF24F379A1}**

restart PC

start registry again and see if the keys from above are still there -> if not, try adding them and restart again. Try adding the keys, go to the sound properties and if the enhancement tab is there, select a feature like "Loudness Equalization" and then see if the registry entries are there after a restart.

if the keys are there, the "Enhancement" tab and "Loudness Equalization" should be back again and working!
```

**P.S: Go through all of the keys in the registry edit mentioned above, as you might find a couple duplicates of the audio device you're using, I had 4. It didn't work when I only changed the first(haven't noticed the others back then)**
P.S2: I had only changed the registry, didn't mess around with the driver thingy he mentioned.
P.S3: I knew that problem was due to the 'audio enhancement' as it was solved once I restored an old Windows Backup & I had a window popup of 'audio enhancements were disabled... would you like to re-enable' and I pressed yes once.. and it immediately returned.